# Which line does the matrix project onto

Tags: linear-transformations

The matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 \\
-1/2 & 1/2
        \end{pmatrix}$$
is a projection matrix. Find the line it projects onto.

In general how am I supposed to find this ?

Comment: Do you know how to find the column space of a matrix?

Comment: yes i do know how to  find column space.

Comment: Well, that gives you the image of the projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line the map transform onto is the line of the fixed points of the linear map. So you have to find the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
        \end{pmatrix}$ for which $$\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 \\
-1/2 & 1/2
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
        \end{pmatrix}$$ Namely the ones of the line $L \equiv x+y=0$

Answer (score 0):

find the eigenvalues of $A$ , one should be zero and the other non-zero.

The line projected onto will be the eigenvector with non-zero eigenvalue.

Because any vector can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors

$$\vec x = a \vec v_z + b \vec v_{nz}$$

where $ A \vec v_z =0 $ and $ A \vec v_{nz} =\lambda \vec v_{nz}$ where $\lambda \ne 0 $

so 
$$A \vec x = aA  \vec v_z+ b A \vec v_{nz} = a(0)+ b \lambda \vec v_{nz}   $$

which is clearly parallel to $ \vec v_{nz} $